# How to properly pass an enum class to the .HTML template in django

Tags: python, html, django

I have an Enum class like this one:

***models.py***

```
.
.
    class Status(Enum):
        New = 1
        Modified = 2
        Done = 3
```

and I want to pass this to the html template in order to iterate over it and use it.

so in my views.py I am passing it like so

***views.py***

```
from models import Status
.
.

status_options = Status    
    return render(request, 'orders.html', {status_options':status_options})
```

and the problem is when I try to use it inside the HTML template I don't get any values

I tried the following

***orders.html***

```
{% for status in status_options %}
    {{ status.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

But I don't get any output

Can anyone provide me with some guides here, please?

Comment: Problem is that `status_options` is callable, so the template engine will call the constructor.

Comment: But when I loop over it in the shell. I am able to get the values. How can I pass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code pass

```
'status_options' : [ x for x in Status ]
```

This is a list not a callable, so you ought to be able to iterate over it in your template:

```
{% for option in status_options %}
    {{ option.name }} {{option.value}}
{% endfor %}
```